# Building a Phonebook

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var search = function(lastName) {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
        for(var i=0; i<contactsLength; i++) {
            if(contacts[i].lastName === lastName) {
                printPerson(contacts[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

the function is set up to take a lastName from the search function and match it to the objects in a contacts array.

```
 if(contacts[i].lastName === lastName) {
                printPerson(contacts[i]);
        }
```

this parcel is what's giving me problems.  it will printPerson correctly, aka print each item of the contacts array, but it won't match the lastName from search() to the lastName in the array.

this is a lesson from codeacademy . com, building a phonebook.

Comment: What do you mean by `it won't match the lastName from search() to the lastName in the array`?

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, where does it go wrong?  What are the values of `contacts[i].lastName` and `lastName` being compared when you suspect the comparison is incorrect?

Comment: What's your sample data and expected output?

Comment: void - it only supposed to log one contact to console, where with the current code it logs the entire array (address book) to console.

Comment: nit - sample data is an array with two people (contacts), expected output is a single contact as in searching for a contact and displaying only that object's info.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you break the loop inside `if`

```
 if(contacts[i].lastName === lastName) {
                printPerson(contacts[i]);
                console.log(contacts[i]);
                break;
        }
```

This way it will do `console.log()` only once at the time of first match.